# how to have a another page.tpl.php file in drupal with different regions and blocks?

Tags: 7, theming

Well, here is the problem. In my site I want to create a plain template and add my own regions and my own blocks. So when the user visits for example www.example.com/register-now the blocks will be different from the main page. I dont like disabling the blocks because when you open Firebug the blocks can be still be seen.

So I have read in [this article](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) that you have to create a new `.tpl.php` file.  So in my case I created the `page__register-now.tpl.php` file. and put that under `drupal/sites/all/themes/ninesixty/` directory.

Then I opened the `template.php` file and tried the below code:

```
function ninesixty_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  $path=drupal_get_path_alias();

  if($path == 'register-now'){
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'node__register';
  }
}
```

Comment: If finding the right name for the template is the problem the [theme developer module](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) is very helpfull.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your path to the register page is `www.example.com/register-now` then you only need to name the page template file appropriately and Drupal should do the rest, you shouldn't need to add anything to `template.php`.

From what you've written, the name of the page template file is wrong. It needs to be renamed to: `page--register-now.tpl.php` (notice the underscores turned to dashes).

After you rename the file (usually after adding any additional template files), make sure to clear all caches from `admin/config/development/performance`.

EDIT: If your page is a node, you can't use the Alias path in the template file, it actually has to be the internal path to the node, e.g. `page--node--123.tpl.php` where 123 is your node's ID.

> The rest are based on the internal path of the current page. **Do not confuse the internal path to path aliases which are not accounted for**.

[See here](http://drupal.org/node/1089656#page-suggestion)

Comment: Ok i see. So i don't need to add anything to my tempate.php file. I will remove the inputted code then from my template.php file and try that again.

Comment: ok I renamed the file to page--register-now.tpl.php remove the code added to template.php and clear the cache and saved the configuration. After that, i clicked on content and created a new basic page and added the html code for the display, entered tha url path alias as register-now and nothing happened. Is this because i am creating the page through the content tab and drupal gets the page.tpl.php theme ???

Comment: Right, if your page is a node, it actually has to have the internal path, e.g. `node/24` in the template file name. So find out your node's ID (hover over the `edit` link and it should say `node/24/edit` where 24 is your node id. Then name your page template file as `page--node--24.tpl.php` replacing 24 with your actual node's id.

Comment: Frustrating but GENIUS. Millions of thanks:):)

Comment: One last question for a multilingual site is there a way to create just one page--node--24.tpl.php file?? Or maybe add some conditions to the template.php file??

Comment: I don't know too much about multilingual, but I think if you have multilingual options set correctly in Drupal then you shouldn't need to worry about having different templates for different languages, as long as the pages look same except the main content.

Comment: Well the multilingual settigns are correct i think. Because translating other pages using the page.tpl.php file worked like a charm. But creating and using the page--node--24.tpl.php for example does not. As when a translation is being added a new node is created which is connected to the original translation. For example node/25 links to other language for node/24 . Anyhow thank you for your help. I might have to think of asking this question in another thread. :)