# Custom login page by Overriding user-login.tpl.php

Tags: theming

This is the code for my templates.php.

```
<?php
    function operationscheck_theme_theme() {
    $items = array();
    $items['user_login'] = array(
   'render element' => 'form',
   'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'operationscheck_theme') . '/templates',
   'template' => 'user-login',
    'preprocess functions' => array(
   'operationscheck_theme_preprocess_user_login'
   ),
);
    $items['user_pass'] = array(
   'render element' => 'form',
   'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'operationscheck_theme') . '/templates',
   'template' => 'user-pass',
   'preprocess functions' => array(
   'operationscheck_theme_preprocess_user_pass'
  ),
);
 $items['user_register_form'] = array(
'render element' => 'form',
'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'operationscheck_theme') . '/templates',
'template' => 'user-register-form',
'preprocess functions' => array(
'operationscheck_theme_preprocess_user_register_form'
 ),
);
return $items;
}
?>

<?php
   function operationscheck_theme_preprocess_user_login(&$vars) {
      $vars['intro_text'] = t('This is my awesome login form');
    }

   function operationscheck_theme_preprocess_user_login(&$vars) {
     $vars['intro_text'] = t('This is my awesome pass form');
   }

function operationscheck_theme_preprocess_user_register_form(&$vars) {
    $vars['intro_text'] = t('This is my super awesome reg form');
   }

 function operationscheck_theme_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $hooks = operationscheck_theme_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)
  $hooks['user_login_block'] = array(
 'template' => 'user-login',
 'arguments' => array('form' => NULL)
 );

// @TODO: Needs detailed comments. Patches welcome!
return $hooks;
}

function operationscheck_theme_preprocess_user_login_block(&$variables) {
  $variables['intro_text'] = t('This is my awesome login formX');
  $variables['rendered'] = drupal_render($variables['form']);
}
 ?>
```

This  is the code for user-login.tpl.php.

```
 <p><?php print render($intro_text); ?></p>
 <div class="yourtheme-user-login-form-wrapper">
 <?php print drupal_render_children($form) ?>
 </div>
```

But when I am flushing the cache, it is still returning the format of old page.tpl.php rather than the simple user login form page. Every file is in its correct place.

Do I have to write an `if` condition to redirect to this user-login.tpl.php?

Comment: I did this ALSO

 http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36054/how-to-have-a-another-page-tpl-php-file-in-drupal-with-different-regions-and-blo

Comment: Why not using [hook_form_alter](https://drupal.org/node/1130422)? There is also an example code by the link.

Comment: Hi t1gor,
Form is there by default just i am not able to redirect to it

Comment: I am not sure I am following - do you need to redirect the form submitted data to another handler? In this case using `hook_form_alter` will allow you to modify the `submit` function to handle the form.

Comment: Well its not that . I am creating a custom theme in which i have a page.tpl.php . SO when i logout from there i need to be redirected to a login page . Thats whats not working friend . hope you understood me now . waiting for response

Comment: I do now. Seems that this is what you're looking for - https://api.drupal.org/comment/39998#comment-39998. You can also use [path_to_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/path_to_theme/7) to check if your theme is used. Hope this helps.