# Add classes to login form fields D 7

Tags: theming, users

I ma trying to add foundation classes to my #user-register-form fields in D7

```
<div class="form-item form-type-textfield form-item-name">
  <label for="edit-name">Username <span class="form-required" title="This field is required.">*</span></label>
 <input class="username form-text required" type="text" id="edit-name" name="name" value="" size="60" maxlength="60">
<div class="description">Spaces are allowed; punctuation is not allowed except for periods, hyphens, apostrophes, and underscores.</div>
</div>
```

I have tried using template overrides like I have with my other custom fields

field--field_homepage_body.tpl.php

But with no luck any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hook form alter gives the whole form - I would like the individual fields

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by altering the form in your custom module **hook_form_alter(){}** or 
in template.php of your active theme.

Just add the classes in the attributes array().

Or you can create a user-login.tpl.php file following this [link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/100483/custom-login-page-by-overriding-user-login-tpl-php), Its already answered here with this code.

```
<?php
    function operationscheck_theme_theme() {
    $items = array();
    $items['user_login'] = array(
   'render element' => 'form',
   'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'operationscheck_theme') . '/templates',
   'template' => 'user-login',

    'preprocess functions' => array(
   'operationscheck_theme_preprocess_user_login'
   ),
);
    $items['user_pass'] = array(
   'render element' => 'form',
   'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'operationscheck_theme') . '/templates',
   'template' => 'user-pass',
   'preprocess functions' => array(
   'operationscheck_theme_preprocess_user_pass'
  ),
);
 $items['user_register_form'] = array(
'render element' => 'form',
'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'operationscheck_theme') . '/templates',
'template' => 'user-register-form',
'preprocess functions' => array(
'operationscheck_theme_preprocess_user_register_form'
 ),
);

return $items;
}
?>

<?php
   function operationscheck_theme_preprocess_user_login(&$vars) {
      $vars['intro_text'] = t('This is my awesome login form');
    }
   function operationscheck_theme_preprocess_user_login(&$vars) {
     $vars['intro_text'] = t('This is my awesome pass form');
   }

function operationscheck_theme_preprocess_user_register_form(&$vars) {
    $vars['intro_text'] = t('This is my super awesome reg form');
   }

 function operationscheck_theme_theme(&$existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  $hooks = operationscheck_theme_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path)

  $hooks['user_login_block'] = array(
 'template' => 'user-login',
 'arguments' => array('form' => NULL)
 );

// @TODO: Needs detailed comments. Patches welcome!
return $hooks;

}

function operationscheck_theme_preprocess_user_login_block(&$variables) {
  $variables['intro_text'] = t('This is my awesome login formX');
  $variables['rendered'] = drupal_render($variables['form']);
}
 ?>
```

Please check if it is the code snippet you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Will be best if you use [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) function. In the hook you can set needed template for the render, form add needed class or any wrapper element